# Show that $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are linear combinations of the other two

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

> Given $\alpha = \langle 1,1,1 \rangle, \beta = \langle 0,1,-1 \rangle, \gamma = \langle 2,0,1 \rangle$, show that each of $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ is a linear combination of the other two. Show that it is impossible to find coefficients $x, y$ and $z$ such that $x \alpha + y \beta + z \gamma = \delta ^1$, where $\delta ^1 = \langle 1,0,0 \rangle$.

What does it mean to show that each $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ is a linear combination of the other two? To me, that means there are scalars $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$x\alpha + y\beta = \gamma $

$x\gamma + y\beta = \alpha$

$x\alpha + y\gamma = \beta$

Then I am struggling to show the above. Let's take $x\alpha + y\beta = \gamma$ for example.

\begin{align}
x \langle 1, 1, 1 \rangle + y \langle 0,1,-1 \rangle &= \langle x, x, x \rangle + \langle 0, y, -y \rangle \\
&= \langle 2,0,1 \rangle
\end{align}

$$\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & -1  & 1
\end{vmatrix}$$

But then it doesn't make sense because in reduced row echelon form, we get

$$\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{vmatrix}$$

So $x$ and $y$ have to equal $0$, but then the above system of linear equations wouldn't be correct.

Comment: You are correct. The question is wrong and the three vectors are linearly independent.

Comment: You can see this easily by checking the equations for $x$ and $y$. The first component directly gives you $x=2$, which makes it impossible to solve the equations for the second and third component.

Comment: @user1551 what do you mean by the question is "wrong"?

Comment: @EvanKim They mean that the question asks you to do something impossible. In my opinion, the most likely thing is that there is a small typo in one of the three vectors.

Comment: @Arthur crap you guys are right. $\gamma = \langle 1,0,2 \rangle$ and not $\langle 2,0,1 \rangle$....I think the problem should make more sense now

Comment: So with the new adjustment, the system is linearly dependent. When the question says to "find coefficients x,y,z", is it implied that x,y,z are unique? Because since the linear equation is dependent, then there should exist infinite solutions right?

Comment: The solution is an (affine) subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$